# Why when drawing line in the scene view between two positions the lines deleted?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What i'm trying to do is to draw lines between two positions and a route of a cube movement without deleting the lines.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int numberOfObjects;
    public GameObject objectToPlace;
    public Vector3 newObjectsSize = new Vector3(5, 5, 5);
    public float speed;

    private int wallsLengthX;
    private int wallsLengthZ;
    private int wallsPosX;
    private int wallsPosZ;
    private int currentObjects;
    private List<GameObject> objects = new List<GameObject>();

    void Start()
    {
        var wi = GetComponent<WallsTest>();
        wallsLengthX = (int)wi.lengthX;
        wallsLengthZ = (int)wi.lengthZ;
        wallsPosX = (int)wi.wallsStartPosition.x;
        wallsPosZ = (int)wi.wallsStartPosition.z;
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Spawn();

        var randpos = GenerateRandomPositions(objects[0]);

        objects[0].transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(objects[0].transform.position,
randpos, (Mathf.Sin(speed * Time.deltaTime)));

        Debug.DrawLine(objects[0].transform.position, randpos, Color.red);
    }

    private void Spawn()
    {
        if (currentObjects != numberOfObjects)
        {
            if (objects.Count != 1) // Why did i make a check if not = 1 ?
            {
                GameObject newObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(objectToPlace);
                newObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(newObjectsSize.x, newObjectsSize.y, newObjectsSize.z);
                newObject.transform.localPosition = GenerateRandomPositions(newObject);
                newObject.name = "Spawned Object";
                newObject.tag = "Spawned Object";
                objects.Add(newObject);

                currentObjects += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private Vector3 GenerateRandomPositions(GameObject newObject)
    {
        float paddingX = Mathf.Clamp(newObject.transform.localScale.x, 0, wallsLengthX) / 2f;
        float paddingZ = Mathf.Clamp(newObject.transform.localScale.z, 0, wallsLengthZ) / 2f;
        float originX = wallsPosX + paddingX - wallsLengthX / 2f;
        float originZ = wallsPosZ + paddingZ - wallsLengthZ / 2f;
        float posx = UnityEngine.Random.Range(originX, originX + wallsLengthX - paddingX);
        float posz = UnityEngine.Random.Range(originZ, originZ + wallsLengthZ - paddingZ);
        float posy = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(posx, 0, posz));

        return new Vector3(posx, posy, posz);
    }
}
```

When i'm using the Debug.DrawLine:

```
Debug.DrawLine(objects[0].transform.position, randpos, Color.red);
```

It's drawing the lines but then delete them. How can i make that it will keep the lines ?

And how can i draw a line in green and also to keep it so it will not delete that show the cube movement route ? The cube is the objects[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you've said yourself, lines are *drawn*, not created.

They aren't objects, and will not have such behavior as *"persisting until deleted"*. They are *"deleted"* every single frame.

You can specify a time for the editor to **keep (re)drawing them** for, using the 4th parameter; but that's the editor taking care of redrawing them every frame; they will still be *"deleted"* at the end of the frame.

Here is the full method signature: `public static void DrawLine(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, Color color = Color.white,`***`float duration = 0.0f`***`, bool depthTest = true);`

A `duration` of `0` means the line is rendered only for the current frame. A value of `0.5f` would mean the line will be (re)rendered for all frames within the next half second.